# Ubuntu Freezes since kernel 4.8.0-36 when USB wifi drive plugged in

Tags: boot, 16.04, wireless, usb, kernel

I've been having trouble booting Ubuntu 16.04 with any kernel after 4.8.0-36. I have been trying a number of things, and was under the impression it may have been a graphics driver issue, but I have discovered the system will actually boot if I remove the Asus USB wifi drive before I boot.

Now I can boot my system using kernels 4.8.0-39, 41, and 44, but as soon as I plug the usb wifi drive in, the whole system freezes and I have to reboot. Are there any ways I can go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /var/log/syslog` soon after it freezes at http://paste.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: Also, with the device inserted: `lsusb`

Comment: @chili555 The entry for `lsusb` of interest is `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:17ab ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N13 802.11n Network Adapter (rev. B1) [Realtek RTL8192CU]`

Comment: @AndroidDev My /var/log/syslog is extremely long. Is there a way I can isolate the relevant portion of it?

Comment: How long is extremely long? If it's less than 5,000 lines just post all of it.

Comment: @AndroidDev For the paste I performed a failed reboot w/ the usb drive still in, then a successful reboot after which it froze when the usb drive was inserted. The details are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24283762/) and the kernel I used was 4.8.0-44.

Comment: @AndroidDev LOL! "5,000 lines..."

Comment: @chili555 - You laugh, but I had to look through this (http://paste.ubuntu.com/24270410/) to find that the OP had a kernel panic due to an out of memory error... (he was complaining that Ubuntu was randomly freezing) it actually wasn't that bad, because you can just search for "`BIOS-provided physical RAM map`", which is very near the beginning of the startup sequence... by searching that way, I found the kernel panic line in less than a minute...

Comment: @chili555 The syslog I posted in this thread was close to 7,000 lines. It's not something I know how to manage, so I'm sure the log just builds up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. I suggest that we blacklist and unload one and see if connectivity improves. Also, let's turn off power saving in Network Manager:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
exit
```

It may take a reboot. Is connectivity improved?

Please check to see that the power saving step was effective:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Make certain that the last line reads:

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

If not, change it, proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You should be all set.

Comment: I will try that, but before I do, these are commands I am not familiar with. If  need to "undo" this modification to the kernel how do I do it?

Comment: You've need to simply edit two files with a text editor such as gedit. A two-minute job.

Comment: Alright - I made that modprobe change and tracked the change it made in the file so I know where to find it. Seems to have worked, I am now online in kernel 4.8.0-44 without any problems. The `sed` line in your script returned an error: `unterminated \`s' command`, so you know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The sed command works for me without complaint. Did you double-check the input? Even better, copy and paste?

Comment: Yea, I tried copy-paste, and I tried after a fresh reboot as well just to see. Gave me the same error.

Comment: I will edit my answer to show how to be certain that the power saving is correct and how to remedy it if not.

Comment: Still trouble with the command, but I followed the manual steps and that seems to be working.